# How to adjust camera clipping for object?

Tags: camera

[image]

Hi there,

I am a complete Blender noob and still don't quite understand how the clipping start and end points work. More specifically, I don't know what, say this Shift X value 0.01m, implies. Is the camera moving 0.01m away from its origin in the +x direction? It seems part of my purple sphere is getting clipped off when I rotated the view to the front. From the side though, I can see the whole object. Would appreciate any feedback. Thanks!

---

@ETHAN DAY, thanks for the response! I  tested out what you said and found that was my camera was a dot relative to all my other objects. How is it then that the camera could have captured all the objects from its perspective? Does the render mode show the view from the camera's perspective or the view it's locked to? Thanks again!

[image]

Comment: Don't worry about the Shift X or Y, what you want to change instead is the clipping. You could make it 0 to turn off camera clipping entirely if you wish. Alternatively you could increase the scale of the object being clipped.

Comment: @NascentSpace, thanks for the tip! I set the clip start to 0, and that worked.

Comment: @user109540, no problem, Happy to help! :) I'm not sure why your camera's origin was relative to all other objects.  As for the render mode, it doesn't show you your scene from the camera's perspective, render mode is simply used to see how everything will look in your final render.  If you do want to see your scene from the perspective of your camera, you can press "0" on your numpad, and it will show you the world from your camera's point of view.

Answer (score 0):

this is a good question.  the shiftX value will shift the camera however many units in the X direction, but the point of origin will stay stationary, if that makes sense.  The camera has a point of origin, like every object. And also like every object, it will rotate around it's point of origin.  In this case, the point of origin is the tip of the camera where all the lines meet (See picture)  [image]
The origin can be seen as a small orange dot.  If you wish to change the origin, there are a number of ways to do this.  You can see all the options by going to: Object-Set Origin; and then choose your preferred position.  Hope I answered your questions correctly!